# Problems with slow queries with InnoDB

Tags: mysql, django

I have a puzzling problem here. I have a django application to view live data from a data acquisition software remotely. Basically, the software provides a script that inserts live data to the database (MySQL). From the web page I can see this live data thanks to flot (JavaScript).

There are two ways to visualize data: if the data is being produced on the fly or if it is stored in the database. There is no differences, the queries to the database are the same for both cases. But while I am watching the data on the fly, the queries of data accumulates a delay proportional to the size of the table. I don't know if the problem comes because in one case (on the fly) the data is being inserted at the same time I make the queries, so the table is growing with the time.

Because of that, I decided to migrate from MyISAM table to InnoDB (ALTER TABLE my_table ENGINE=InnoDB), because I have heard that InnoDB is optimized for reading and writing at the same time. This table of data is very large, because of the big amount of data. Now, this table has about 6 millions of rows. So, I converted the table to InnoDB. And now, the problem is worse, because I have slow queries (about 5 seconds) in both cases (on the fly and when there is no inserted data).

I have heard a lot of optimization tools but I don't understand so much about MySQL. What about primary keys to optimize the search? How this works?

Please, I need to solve this. I would appreciate any help received.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any checks to see if data exists before it is inserted or are you using Update/Where statements? If you're doing straight INSERT INTO statements I don't imagine you'd have an indexing problem, but if you're checking records first, or updating you might. Rule of thumb I have is that if a column appears in a where clause, or in a Django filter() or get(), it should be indexed. In Django you can do this on the model with db_index=True.

Comment: I already have Django configured with db_index=True for the columns that appear in where clauses. As the application works with live data (INSERTs and SELECTs), the ideal solution would be to query the last data inserted. As this is difficult to perform, I would accept a error margin. But my SELECT clauses takes more and more time along the time (2, 3, 4 seconds), and this is not desired for a live view of data. Help?

Comment: SELECT clauses are slow when data is being inserted at the same time (INSERT INTO clause), but when the data is historical (already ended the insertion of data), the queries are performed correctly.